# What circumstances would lead to someone involuntarily having nuclear codes placed in their heart?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, nuclear-war

Going off the quote from this link - https://taskandpurpose.com/president-nuclear-authority-kill-heart-fisher-protocol/

The gist is that in order for the president to launch a nuclear weapon, he must kill someone first, and extract the nuclear codes embedded in their heart.

In a fictional (but plausible) World War II context, how could this occur logically, and for dramatic purposes, without consent? What would the subject have to do to be put in that position, yet the reader can still sympathize with her? For example, if the subject committed a petty crime like jaywalking or speeding, this is a very extreme punishment. However, if they were a serial killer, the reader would not be able to sympathize with her.

Comment: And when the Russian/DPRK nukes are already inbound?

Comment: "*In a fictional (but plausible) World War II context*".  This makes no sense, since the atomic bomb was so new/experimental in WW2.  Besides, there was a **lot** of debate about whether or not to drop the bombs.

Comment: This is off-topic, as you are looking for plot help.  However, if the problem is that you want an extreme punishment for something that won't look bad to a modern audience, consider making her a "sexual deviant" by 1950s mores.  She could be a lesbian for example.  Or if that doesn't work for you, her beast of a husband was trying to have his way with her when she wasn't in the mood.  She knocked a metal sculpture into his head and he died.  For "reasons," she was convicted.  Or simply make her innocent, wrongfully convicted, later exonerated and freed, but she still has the codes.

Comment: To the collective persons who voted to close this question you are in error. For more information, refer to https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/when-should-i-close-a-question-as-too-story-based and see if the criteria fit. To save you time, they don't. Yes the question has an extremely improbable scenario, but it isn't asking to build a plot.

Comment: @Brythan What expertise you may have, understanding of what constitutes isn't among them. Had the folk who voted to close this question bothered to read the criteria for story-based carefully they would have concluded they don't apply.

Comment: @a4android, I found this question via the reopen queue.  Though I believe you and I respect each other, we've often disagreed about what should be closed and what shouldn't.  This one isn't obviously in the clear at all.  It violates at least two of the "must be closed if any" bullets.  If the Q is seriously reworded to ask, "what would the government need to do to convince the population to allow this atrocity to happen for the sake of saving the nation" then it's a WB question.  But the OP's not quite asking it that way.  Maybe you can get the OP into chat to help him understand (*continue*)

Comment: @a4android, how to ask questions, but as it stands, this question looks like storybuilding vs. worldbuilding.  Frankly, to be WB the answers should apply to the context of the world (tech, society, physionomy, etc.) rather than the context of just a handful of people.  And the story's readers don't count in that sum.

Comment: @JBH This is not in the context of a handful of people, it is in context of US President & nuclear strategy. The Presidency of the USA, even a fictional version of it, is a worldbuilding element. The basis of story-based is determining what a character(s) should do, while for worldbuilding it is how it is should be done. The question asks how in the sense of what circumstance this might be done in a fictional world; that is worldbuilding.

Comment: @JBH Yes we do respect each other & disagree frequently. Sorry which bullet points does it violate? Your suggested rewording seems to change the form & intent of the question radically. Please understand this question isn't to my taste (apologies to the OP), however, I do object to its being closed in error.

Comment: @Brythan You should understand my previous comment was focused the first sentence of your comment in the light of what I consider an erroneous VTC. On the other hand, I appreciate and support the rest of your comment because of your suggestions to help the OP constructing his world.

Comment: @a4android, bullets #2 and #4.  The OP isn't asking about POTUS (and while suggesting that any question involving POTUS or POTUS-like people is automatically WB due to their influence assuages my national pride, bullet #7 says that's only valid IF the Q is about WB), the OP is asking how to make the target of this infamous scenario more palatable to the reader of the story.  That's storybuilding.  Asking how the Government would set this nasty little mess up to be palatable to "The People," that would be worldbuilding.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that my answer focused on larger groups of people, with almost nothing regarding the way POTUS might think.

Comment: It might be easier to take this to meta, but the question is basically:  how do I make my character likeable after giving her a capital-punishment-level penalty?  That's all plot and negligible worldbuilding.  We often misuse story-based, but this is exactly the reason why we have that close reason.

Comment: @JBH Which post on story-based? It's hard to follow especially if it's the post I linked above where the bullet points are unnumbered.

Comment: @JBH Assuming #2 is; "Asking about a specific individual". Well, that doesn't apply. The question is looking for a suitable class of victim not a specific person. It's not: Would Herbert Hoover chop open Al Capone to get the nuclear codes. I have used historical figures to demonstrate specific persons. The question itself doesn't suggest specific persons. It talks about classes of possible victims.

Comment: @JBH Assuming #4 is: "Lack of context, if it is unclear how the question relates to building a world". This one is a stinker. It's a bonking stupid criterion which is hard to make any sense of. Best avoided because it only leads to confusion. However, it is not unreasonable to give question the benefit of the doubt. The fact a question is here on WB SE suggests in all probably worldbuilding is involved. The OP could begin the question with "In a world where  flying monkeys exist .." & now it's about worldbuilding. This criterion deserves to be ignored. What were they thinking?

Comment: @JBH If the actual gist of the question is about making the concept palatable to readers, then it's in the wrong place & should be migrated to Writers SE. However, closure on the grounds of Story-based is still wrong. Because the criteria for story-based haven't been met.

Comment: @a4android, I agree about the bullets, I replaced them with numbers for future reference.  I don't interpret a "specific person" as a person by name because that's senseless in any context.  What does giving them a name mean?  A "specific person" is one person, not a society or even a community.  That's part of what fails the WB test.  Criteria #4 may deserve to be ignored, but you're the one who linked the question.  If we want to change the "relevant critera" then that should be done in meta, not here.  (*continued*)

Comment: @a4android, and we've been siding for a while now on the idea of taking the OP at their word.  I'm not going to interpret a question that specifically states it's looking for help placating its readers as anything other than storybuilding.  As far as I'm concered, any question that's story-based belongs on Writers.SE by definition.  I think we've hashed this one into a corner without improving the linked meta question, haven't we?  I'm all for improving it.  I think most of our VTC reasons are very poorly defined, and the definitions are hard to find.

Comment: @JBH Story-based isn't the same as storybuilding. Here story-based is a VTC, whereas storybuilding is about writing. No-one had suggested it should be migrated instead they jumped on the wrong VTC. WB's VTC reasons aren't easy to find & the criteria need to be teased out. More challenging than it needs to be. This should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest challenge with this plan is that, to support a reasonable reaction time, this person has to be close to the president.  Having a serial killer near the president continuously strikes me as *highly* unreasonable.  Also, this individual would need the highest security clearances, as they would have to be let into the war rooms whenever the president is discussing policy.  It's hard to pass [Yankee White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yankee_White) as a violent criminal.

If this person did not volunteer, then we have to recognize that they will likely want to escape the meat-cleaver wielding POTUS.  It is highly unlikely that they will voluntarily just stay close to the president after being violated in this way.  The football is always close to the president.  It was [noteworthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_football) that President Reagan was separated from it after being shot, when medical staff cut his clothes from him.  Accordingly, this individual is going to be on a mighty short leash.  I would expect them to be physically chained with several chaperones ensuring they cannot run away.

Which leads to the real worldbuilding question for your world.  Right now, the football is an inconspicuous looking briefcase.  In your world, the equivalent of the football is a chained involuntary slave with a potential death sentence, who must always be within photography distance of the president.  They would probably have to be gagged the entire time to ensure they stay quiet. What sort of world will find this acceptable?  What had to have been going through the minds of the lawmakers when they wrote the laws regarding control of nukes?

So as for the circumstances where a person may be involuntarily pressed into service this way?  I'd say the circumstances are "The entire nation has lost their marbles."  Most likely [John Kramer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_(franchise)) was elected as senate majority leader, or something to that effect.

Comment: My goodness you've actually answered the question. Security clearances needed to be a problem. The code containers can be disposed of with extreme prejudice when they're no longer needed or replaced. The Fisher proposal is a wicked concept: Murder one man to launch thermonuclear megadeath. To think we're on the brink where this seems almost sensible. Plus one for a good & sane answer (& overcoming the odds on this topic).